# What's eating up my storage?

Tags: storage, samsung-galaxy-tab-a

I selected all the folders of my Internal Storage, and the details say it is 11.64 GB. But, on the left bar, it shows Internal Storage [31.17/32.00 GB]. Screenshot of My Files application of my phone:

[image]

**ABOUT DEVICE**

[image]
[image]
[image]

**QUESTIONS**

1. How is this possible?
2. I can't download any application and install it. How to free the *HIDDEN STORAGE*?

Comment: The internal storage is just the section accessible by nearly every app. But there is also the app-private where only each app can access it's own files. So a file-manager app can only access it's own files and do not show the size of the other app data.

Comment: Additional note: those 32 GB also include the Android System, where not only you cannot access all files to read, but you cannot write at all. So no chance to "use" any free space that might exist there. PS: you might also wish to consult our [storage tag-wiki](/tags/storage/info) for further details, including to free up storage. Most of our tags have such wikis attached, always worth a look :)

Comment: okay @Izzy and Robert